# AWS-Lambda only partially downloads a file from web

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda function that downloads an mp3 file of a random YT video from a link (in the code). 
When running locally, the file finishes the download and the filesize in the end is ~ 8mb.
But when executed on Lambda, it only downloads about 17kb~ of the file.

```
let link = "http://cdl29.convert2mp3.net/download.php?id=youtube_ivpU-4LJaZk&key=hvjquS9UNKoq&d=y"

request
.get(link)
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("/tmp/name"))
.on("finish", () => {
    console.log(fs.statSync("/tmp/name").size/1000000.0)
    fs.readFile('/tmp/name', function(err, content) {
        if (err) return callback(err)
        console.log("Got here")
    })
})
```

No errors, everything runs succesfully. But it seems like the `fs.createWriteStream` finishes before the downloading is actually finished while running on Lambda. Any ideas?

Edit: Actually, with the help Elliot Nelson, I saw that it's downloading an HTML file. Which is weird, because I'm passing a direct link to the script.
Seems like it just redirects to the home page of the website which I never saw to happen on my home machine.

Comment: Curious, have you looked at the file content at all?  I'm wondering if the downloaded temp file actually looks like the first 17KB of the video you want, or if instead it is something else, perhaps a large blob of HTML (like an error page).  Also, you might try also appending a `.on("error")` handler to your pipe, in addition to the `finish`, and print the error (if any) to the console.

Comment: Oh, how did I miss that one? It is, in fact, actually HTML.

Comment: This is not the first time Lambda acts like this. When I open a link on my PC (even with VPN in USA), it downloads a file. But when opened on Lambda, it.. redirects to the main website? How can that one be possible?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your lambda finishes the execution before the download is finished.

What the node version you're using?

If it's Node 6 -> you're not calling the callback after the successful download, but only during the error

If it's Node 8 -> forget about the callbacks alltogether and use a promise instead. The AWS actually expects you to return a promise that is either resolved or rejected, indicating either success or error.

```
module.exports.handle = event => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

   let link = "http://cdl29.convert2mp3.net/download.php?id=youtube_ivpU-4LJaZk&key=hvjquS9UNKoq&d=y"

  request
  .get(link)
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("/tmp/name"))
  .on("finish", () => {
      console.log(fs.statSync("/tmp/name").size/1000000.0)
      fs.readFile('/tmp/name', function(err, content) {
        console.log("Got here")
        err ? reject(err) : resolve(content);
      })
   })

});
```

Comment: I found out that it's actually downloading HTML instead of the song that it's supposed to. But it's weird, cause the link is direct and immidietly starts a download.

Comment: either way look at the logs. Right now your lambda finishes its job after 1 second, but actually stays alive until it times out, generating an error and higher cost (you pay for execution count + MB of memory per second). You need to either return a promise or call a callback upon success, or you waste your money. There are also limitations to how many instance of lambda you can ran at once, so if you have lot of users and your lambda ends only after god knows how long (because you're not calling the callback), then you're gonna have some issues

Comment: Um, I'm sorry, but did You actually read the question before answering it?

1. I did mention, that I think it's running for 1 second. But then I said that it's not and described the problem.
2. In the question, I said that it doesn't have any errors and runs succesfully.
3. Of course this is not the whole code. You can easily see that because there are no import statements.

Comment: I did. That last comment was just the side remark as I didn't see the final callback

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're seeing a difference in behavior due to logic on the server.

Possibilities:

(1) You are logged in (perhaps without realizing it) on your local browser. Try going to the same link in an incognito window to test this. The service might require credentials or else it redirects you.

(2) The service is checking the user agent. You could test this by trying to CURL the URL locally, instead of going through the browser.

(3) It's blocking by IP -- does the exact same javascript logic work on your machine? If you have access to it, you could try the same code on your machine, another machine, perhaps an EC2 instance, etc., and see what criteria it might be checking.

If all else fails, you could contact the administrator of the website directly, explain what you're doing, and see if there is a workaround. They may be explicitly blocking what you are trying to do.

Comment: All 3 aren't the case here, the exact same script works perfectly fine on my machine.
But thanks for the advices anyway :)